# require: command not found

Tags: ruby, bash

`which ruby` - `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

`.bash_profile` has the above path

I have not left any trailing spaces before `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in the ruby script

When I try to run `sh ruby_script`, it gives `require: command not found`. It is not able to recognize any of the ruby commands.

I checked all the other posts getting the same error, and fixed everything accordingly. What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Running `sh ruby_script` is wrong. You must run `ruby ruby_script` instead. If the file is executable run `./ruby_script`.

Answer (score 1):

`sh ruby_script` is invoking the shell. Try either

```
/path/to/ruby_script
```

or

```
ruby /path/to/ruby_script
```

Comment: Woah worked! Silly me, was trying to run ruby script via sh. Thanks!

Comment: To wit, `sh script` runs the script with `sh`, regardless of the shebang line. The script needs to be marked executable and run by itself in order for the shebang to play any role.